# How can I scrape the pageviews statistics from all the articles on the English Wikipedia?

Tags: web-scraping, wikipedia, pageviews

Here is a link to an already made pageview tool: https://tools.wmflabs.org/pageviews/#start=2016-02-10&end=2016-02-29&project=en.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=user&pages=Cat|Dog

But you can't see the pageviews from all the articles of Wikipedia at the same time. Which article has the most views and which article has the lowest.

Hopefully you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

There is an [API endpoint for the daily top 1000 most-viewed pages](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/?doc#!/Pageviews_data/get_metrics_pageviews_top_project_access_year_month_day), which is updated a few hours after midnight (UTC).

For example: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikipedia/all-access/2016/02/29

```
{
  "items": [
  {
    "project": "en.wikipedia",
    "access": "all-access",
    "year": "2016",
    "month": "02",
    "day": "29",
    "articles": [
      {
        "article": "Main_Page",
        "views": 21384819,
        "rank": 1
      },
      {
        "article": "Special:Search",
        "views": 2211296,
        "rank": 2
      },
      {
        "article": "Steve_Blake",
        "views": 2084367,
        "rank": 3
      },
      ...
```

- It includes popular Wikipedia pages that are not "articles" per se, like the Main Page, the Search page, and a few others. You can filter these out by checking for titles on English Wikipedia that begin with Special:, Template:, User:, Talk:, etc.
- You may notice a few pages with a large number of pageviews due to spiders or bots. Those will hopefully be [filtered out, eventually](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T123442).

There isn't currently an API for the least-viewed page. You can also get [aggregate stats](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/?doc#!/Pageviews_data/get_metrics_pageviews_aggregate_project_access_agent_granularity_start_end) for all of Wikipedia or [pageviews for a particular article](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/?doc#!/Pageviews_data/get_metrics_pageviews_per_article_project_access_agent_article_granularity_start_end).

Comment: Thank you @slaporte for the links and tips! Very helpful.